# Sending Email from the windows phone 8 app

Tags: email

I am creating a windows phone 8 app. I have created a PDF document and now I want to send this PDF to an email address. But I do not know how to proceed with this.

Please Help me.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(First search search search then ask)

see this one [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394003%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

To send normal email,you should add:

```
    using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;
```

to your code, and then for personalizing and going to the mail app add this:

```
    EmailComposeTask emailComposeTask = new EmailComposeTask();

    emailComposeTask.Subject = "message subject";
    emailComposeTask.Body = "message body";
    emailComposeTask.To = "recipient@example.com";
    emailComposeTask.Cc = "cc@example.com";
    emailComposeTask.Bcc = "bcc@example.com";

    emailComposeTask.Show();
```

for sending attachemnts see these links once

[end-email-with-attachments-without-using-emailcomposetask-with-mailmessage](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/send-email-with-attachments-without-using-emailcomposetask-with-mailmessage)

[how-to-send-automated-emails-with-attachments-from-windows-phone-apps](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-send-automated-emails-with-attachments-from-windows-phone-apps)

Comment: Thanks Akbar for your reply. It helped me a lot.

Comment: if you think that i am helped you then accept this as answer,so that new people can easily find this.Thank you all the best

Comment: But how do I know , that mail sent successfully or sending failed ?